# Python compute correlation of a single variable between groups

Tags: python, correlation, panel-data

I'd like to compute the correlation of the variable "hours" between two groups in a panel data. Specifically, I'd like to compute the correlation of hours between groups A and B with group C. So the end result would contain two numbers: corr(hours_A, hours_C), and corr(hours_B, hours_C).

I have tried:

```
data.groupby('group').corr()
```

But it gave me the correlation between "hours" and "other variables" within each group, but I want the correlation of just the "hours" variable across two groups. I'm new to Python, so any help is welcome!

| group | year | hours | other variables |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | 2784 | 567 |
| A | 2001 | 2724 | 567 |
| A | 2002 | 2715 | 567 |
| B | 2000 | 2301 | 567 |
| B | 2001 | 2612 | 567 |
| B | 2002 | 2489 | 567 |
| C | 2000 | 2190 | 567 |
| C | 2001 | 2139 | 567 |
| C | 2002 | 2159 | 567 |

Update:

Thank you for answering my question!
I eventually figured out some code of my own, but my code is not as elegant as the answers provided. For what it's worth, I'm posting it here.

```
df = df.set_index(['group','year'])
df = df.unstack(level=0)
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).year
df.columns = df.columns.rename(['variables',"group"])
df.xs('hours',  level="variables", axis=1).corr()
```

Indexing year isn't necessary for the correlation, but if I want to create cross sections of the data later, it might come in handy.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
Since you have not attempted a solution or researched an algorithm, you do not yet have a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I updated my question to include the code that I tried and didn't work.

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: The line you posted is not an attempt to correlate the groups you specified.  As the documentation tells you, it correlates columns of the given DF.

Comment: Thank you. Just appended an update with my code.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it is not the best way to do it but I believe this will get you on your way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = data[['group', 'year', 'hours']]

data_new = data.set_index(['year', 'group']).unstack(['group'])
final_df = pd.DataFrame(data_new.to_numpy(), columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])

final_df.corr()
```

I will also leave the process to (I think) reproduce your problem for anyone who wishes to give it a try!

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_str = '''A|2000|2784|567
A|2001|2724|567
A|2002|2715|567
B|2000|2301|567
B|2001|2612|567
B|2002|2489|567
C|2000|2190|567
C|2001|2139|567
C|2002|2159|567'''.split('\n')

data = pd.DataFrame([x.split('|') for x in data_str], columns=['group', 'year', 'hours', 'other_variables'])

data['hours'] = data['hours'].astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you! I did not know about the to_numpy() method, happy to learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply list to the groups and then convert to Series, transpose, and then call corr() on the data.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

>>> data = StringIO("""group,year,hours,other,variables
A,2000,2784,567
A,2001,2724,567
A,2002,2715,567
B,2000,2301,567
B,2001,2612,567
B,2002,2489,567
C,2000,2190,567
C,2001,2139,567
C,2002,2159,567""")
>>> df = pd.read_csv(data)
>>> df.groupby('group')['hours'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T.corr()

          0         1         2
0  1.000000  0.771752  0.898470
1  0.771752  1.000000  0.972589
2  0.898470  0.972589  1.000000
```

How does this work? The groupby + apply(list) produces the following, which is a Series with three rows, each being a list of three items.

```
A    [2784, 2724, 2715]
B    [2301, 2612, 2489]
C    [2190, 2139, 2159]
```

The apply(pd.Series) converts the list in each row to a series. You then have to transpose with the T operator to get the data for each group in a single column.

```
          0     1     2
group
A      2784  2724  2715
B      2301  2612  2489
C      2190  2139  2159

transposed is

group     A     B     C
0      2784  2301  2190
1      2724  2612  2139
2      2715  2489  2159
```

If you only want the two values, it would be

```
>>> df.groupby('group')['hours'].apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T.corr().iloc[1:3,0].values
array([-0.86594029,  0.86783525])
```

In this example, you use `iloc` to get the second and third rows in the first column (python indexes are zero-based) and then the `values` property of a `Series` to return an array rather than a `Series`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I would never have thought to do it this way!